# Will ESXi 5.5 in standalone mode (free) support fibre channel SAN?

Tags: vmware-esxi, fibre-channel, blade-server

I have a HP blade in a C7000 enclosure and a new 3PAR StoreServ 7200 over Fibre Channel.
Today we use DAS and have not virtualized our SQL servers.

My goal is:
SQL Server 2008 -> WS2012R2 -> ESXi 5.5 -> Blade G8 -> C7000 Enclosure -> FC Switch -> 3PAR StoreServ 7200.

The hardware part is supported by HP/3PAR.
I will use ESXi 5.5 standalone, managed by vSphere 5.5 directly.
I will do this since I only want a single VM on that host.
We use vCenter for the rest of the VM's on different Blade hosts, but our SQL server is 1 VM on 1 host, therefore the free direct management.

I just have one question:
Since I do not purchase a vCenter license and therefore run the ESXi as "free", will I have the same options regarding storage, as a vCenter enrolled ESXi host?
I want to see the FC/3PAR storage from within vSphere on my ESXi host, so I can add this as storage.

Please advise, since I must prepare all servers, vmware, windows, SAN switches etc. and have it all up and running before the 3PAR techie comes and install 3PAR. 
He asks for 4 FC wires to plug his 3PAR into, the rest is on me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

> Will ESXi 5.5 in standalone mode (free) support fibre channel SAN?

Yes